# HAAR face detection doesnt work as expected

Tags: python, opencv, haar-classifier

I'm currently working on face detection using OpenCV. I finished training by using my positive and negative images with a cascade trainer GUI. However when I run my code to test for face detection, only the first image works(only when .detectMultiScale is set to gray,1.01,7) and it doesn't work on the other images.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('classifier/cascade.xml')

img = cv2.imread('p/pic2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.01,7)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

All of my positive images are in gray scale and their size is (600,600). My negative image sizes are bigger but not in gray scale. There are 80 positive images and 160 negative. I'm sure if this is what's effecting the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all your both negative and positive images should be in
  grayscale.
- Secondly, you didnt talk about how you labeled your    positive
  images to get positive vectors.
- Thirdly, your number of    images(pos and neg) is not enough and
  difficult to get good results.(900 neg and 1800 pos is suggested as minimum)
- Lastly,I assume you are using [opencv_traincascade](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) so in which stage of xml did you finish training.

My suggestion is following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88HdqNDQsEk) by following [the documentation](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/). I used this tutorial and trained many objects before so it is good to follow

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this code (without any changes) then only one image (pic2.png) is processed. For multiple images you need to loop through the image paths from a particular folder.

Comment: When I run this for pic1.png it works, but for all of the other ones it doesn't.